# Swap largest and smallest number in matrix

Tags: php, arrays

I want to write a program that swaps largest and smallest number in multidimensional array. I've given dimensions to an empty array $arrNxm that has numbers from 1 to 25.
Please check my code and help me with my problem.

For Instance:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

New order should be:

```
25 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 1
```

```
$arrNxm = array();

$intRows = 5;
$intCols = 5;

$intValue = 1;

for($row = 0; $row < $intRows; $row++)
{
  for($col = 0; $col < $intCols; $col++)
  {
    $arrNxm[$row][$col] = $intValue++;
  }
}

var_dump($arrNxm);

$intLargest = 0;
$intSmallest = $intLargest;


for($i = 0; $i < count($arrNxm); $i++)
{
  foreach($arrNxm as $row)
  {
    foreach($row as $cell)
    {
      if($cell > $intLargest)
      {
        $intLargest = $cell;
      } else if ($cell < $intSmallest)
      {
        $intSmallest = $cell;
      }
    }
  }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arrNxm);

var_dump($intLargest);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($intSmallest);
```

I'm getting only reversed arrays, like first array of numbers is `25 24 23 22 21` and last `5 4 3 2 1` which is not the goal.

Comment: Is this a 2D matrix?

Comment: Yes...i've given empty array values for column $intCols = 5 and for rows $intRows = 5.

Comment: Didn't get it. How does your 2D array for 5x5 look like? What if there are multiple same minimums and maximums? Which one would you want to swap?

Comment: It goes from 1 to 25...that's how my array looks like, and the idea is to change position of lowest and highest number

Comment: Then why loop? First element will always be the smallest and last element will always be the largest.

Comment: I'm using loop to add values of rows and columns to an empty array...and after that I'm using the loop to count all numbers from array and then to try to swap somehow values of smallest and largest...

Comment: ok, for your requirement below answers will help.

Comment: This question is not composed very clearly.  You say multidimensional but list numbers as one dimensional.  Please edit.

Comment: I'm sorry for mistake...hope now question is understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my code :

```
$arrNxm = array();

$intRows = 5;
$intCols = 5;

$maxrow = $minrow  = $maxcol = $mincol = 0;
$maxval = $minval = 0;

for($row = 0; $row < $intRows; $row++)
{
  for($col = 0; $col < $intCols; $col++)
  {
    if($arrNxm[$row][$col] >$maxval)
    {
        $maxval = $arrNxm[$row][$col];
        $maxrow = $row;
        $maxcol = $col;
    }
    if($arrNxm[$row][$col] <$minval)
    {
        $minval = $arrNxm[$row][$col];
        $minrow = $row;
        $mincol = $col;
    }
  }
}

$arrNxm[$minrow][$mincol] = $maxval;
$arrNxm[$maxrow][$maxcol] = $minval;
```

Comment: This is similar solution I already tried but code looks lot better then mine. I tried to run this code but I'm getting same errors I already had, like undefined offset...

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation.

Comment: This code used two for to get index of max value and min value. After it will swap value of min and max with index max value and min value.

Comment: @AuNguyen When I run this code I have errors like undefined offset. can you help me?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of what was wrong with the OP's code and how your answer overcomes the problem.   On Stack Overflow,  code-only answers are low-value because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: @AuNguyen I've tried to experiment a little with the code you gave me, and I wanted to run same code and get same results but using empty array, and I'm having issues as I cannot find the right solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the min and max value, then do replace.

```
$array = range(1,25);
$min_index = $max_index = 0;
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if($v < $array[$min_index]){
        $min_index = $k;
    }
    if($v > $array[$max_index]){
        $max_index = $k;
    }
}
$min = $array[$min_index];
$array[$min_index] = $array[$max_index];
$array[$max_index] = $min;
```

Comment: This code gives a right result, bu the idea is not to use range of numbers. The rule I must follow in code is to have an empty array and to have values that I'm giving to array..like $IntRows = 5 and $ntCols = 5, and then I have numbers from 1 to 25 in matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the array using `sort()` function and just swap the min and max position of the array and just chunk the array using `array_chunk()` to get your desired output.

```
$arrNxm = range(1,25);
sort($arrNxm);
$number_of_element = count($arrNxm);
$temp = $arrNxm[0];
$arrNxm[0] = $arrNxm[$number_of_element-1];
$arrNxm[$number_of_element-1] = $temp;
print_r(array_chunk($arrNxm,5));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have to use pure logic, without any php functions that could help me out...